# Does either klazuka/Kal or EventKit handle multiple calendars?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a iPad app that needs to have multiple calendars, one for each employee, and  one giving a consolidated view of all of the employee's calendars.

Does either Kai or EventKit support this requirement?  If not, is there a calendar API that will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Kit does this... Provided that you have an EKEventStore called myEventStore, define the calendar array like so:

```
NSArray *calendarArray = myEventStore.calendars;
```

and fetch the events like this

```
NSPredicate *fetchAllEvents = [self.myEventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:calendarArray]; //you can modify this predicate, just keep calendar:calendarArray
NSArray *allEvents = [self.myEventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchAllEvents];
```

Comment: @spokane-dude No problem. I was actually having this same problem with one of my apps a little while back and came across this...